# How to use multicore and multithreads to get maximum capacity of cpu and I/O to speed up Program in c++?

Tags: c++, multithreading, openmp, multicore

I wrote a c++ program that runs with python multiprocess and multithread.
Our input include multiple folders with more than 20000 files in it,
We read files from disk and then process it and write it to disk in the end.

Python's job is to devide these files between threads.

Ps. I read files with c++

I want to try c/c++, multicore and multithreads to speed up my program.

There are some packages like openmp and ppl, pthreads ... but i cant use their ability, it seems that open mp use maximum capacity of cpu (100%) however it didnt improve process speed ....I tested 300 files and results are:  -without multicore and multithreads, it takes 15 second (20%cpu usage)  -with it takes 30 second (100% cpu usage)

I also check disk usage and it shows that 3-4% of disk is working which is very low for this kind of work.

I couldn't find the reason and what is wrong with it.

I apperciate any help, and here is my code:

```
template<typename Vector>
auto split_vector(const Vector& v, unsigned number_lines) {
    using Iterator = typename Vector::const_iterator;
    vector<Vector> rtn;
    Iterator it = v.cbegin();
    const Iterator end = v.cend();

    while (it != end) {
        Vector v;
        back_insert_iterator<Vector> inserter(v);
        const auto num_to_copy = min(static_cast<unsigned>(distance(it, end)), number_lines);
        copy(it, it + num_to_copy, inserter);
        rtn.push_back(move(v));
        advance(it, num_to_copy);
    }

    return rtn;
}



bool ListFiles(wstring inPath, wstring outPath, vector<pair<wstring, wstring>>& inputFiles, wstring mask) {
    HANDLE hFind = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;
    WIN32_FIND_DATA ffd;
    wstring spec;
    wstring spec2;
    stack<wstring> directories;
    stack<wstring> outDirectories;

    directories.push(inPath);
    inputFiles.clear();
    outDirectories.push(outPath);

    while (!directories.empty()) {
        inPath = directories.top();
        spec = inPath + L"\\" + mask;
        directories.pop();

        outPath = outDirectories.top();
        spec2 = outPath + L"\\" + mask;
        outDirectories.pop();

        hFind = FindFirstFile(spec.c_str(), &ffd);
        if (hFind == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
            return false;
        }

        do {
            if (wcscmp(ffd.cFileName, L".") != 0 &&
                wcscmp(ffd.cFileName, L"..") != 0) {
                if (ffd.dwFileAttributes & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY) {
                    directories.push(inPath + L"\\" + ffd.cFileName);
                    outDirectories.push(outPath + L"\\" + ffd.cFileName);
                }
                else {
                    inputFiles.push_back(make_pair(inPath + L"\\" + ffd.cFileName, outPath + L"\\" + L"m_" + ffd.cFileName));
                }
            }
        } while (FindNextFile(hFind, &ffd) != 0);

        if (GetLastError() != ERROR_NO_MORE_FILES) {
            FindClose(hFind);
            return false;
        }

        FindClose(hFind);
        hFind = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;
    }
    return true;
}

void Thread(vector<pair<wstring, wstring>>& v)
{
    vector<thread> tv;
    for (int i = 0; i < v.size(); i++) {
        tv.emplace_back(work, v[i].first /*input file*/, v[i].second  /*output file*/);
    }

    for (auto& t : tv) {
        t.join();
    }
}


void Async(vector<pair<wstring, wstring>>v)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < v.size(); i++) {
        future<void> result(async(launch::async, work, v[i].first /*input file*/, v[i].second  /*output file*/));
    }
}


void Process(vector<pair<wstring, wstring>>& v, const int threadCount)
{
    int i, n = v.size();
#pragma omp parallel
    {
#pragma omp  for default(none) private(i) shared(v) schedule(dynamic, threadCount)
        for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            try
            {
                work(v[i].first /*input file*/, v[i].second  /*output file*/);
            }
            catch (const exception& exc)
            {
                printf("%s\n", exc.what());
            }
        }

    };
}


void Process2(vector<pair<wstring, wstring>>& v, const int threadCount)
{
    auto vectors = split_vector(v, threadCount);
    int i, n = vectors.size();

#pragma omp parallel
    {
#pragma omp  for  nowait
        for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            try
            {
                Async(vectors[i]);
            }
            catch (const exception& exc)
            {
                printf("%s\n", exc.what());
            }
        }

    };
}

void Process3(vector<pair<wstring, wstring>>& v, const int threadCount)
{
    auto vectors = split_vector(v, threadCount);
    int i, n = vectors.size();

#pragma omp parallel
    {
#pragma omp  for  nowait
        for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            try
            {
                Thread(vectors[i]);
            }
            catch (const exception& exc)
            {
                printf("%s\n", exc.what());
            }
        }

    };
}


int wmain(int argc, wchar_t** argv) {

    if (argc != 7) return EXIT_FAILURE;

    auto start = high_resolution_clock::now();

    const wstring input_dir(argv[1]);
    if (input_dir.empty()) return EXIT_FAILURE;


    const wstring output_dir(argv[2]);
    if (output_dir.empty())  return EXIT_FAILURE;


    int p = thread::hardware_concurrency();

    int processor_count = _wtoi(argv[3]) > p ? p : _wtoi(argv[3]);
    int thread_count = _wtoi(argv[4]);
    int level = _wtoi(argv[5]);

    vector<pair<wstring, wstring>> inFiles;
    ListFiles(input_dir, output_dir, inFiles, L"*");
    omp_set_num_threads(processor_count);
    Process(inFiles, thread_count);
    //Process2(inFiles, thread_count);
    //Process3(inFiles, thread_count);


    auto stop = high_resolution_clock::now();
    auto duration = duration_cast<seconds>(stop - start);
    printf("Duration: %d", duration);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Reading/Writing on the disk in parallel can actually be slower than doing it in sequential regarding your hardware. HDD are especially bad for multithreading while most recent SSD are fine with that (mainly reading not so much for writting). The slowdown in parallel I/O is often due to a *lower locality* and a *smaller buffers* (HDD likes working on *big sequential* chunks with *few requests*). Thus, if you target HDDs, I think this is pointless. Otherwise, please benchmark your disk with the sequential code to check if parallelization worth the effort.

Comment: Also Process2 and 3 where you try combining omp with C++ threading are most probably a bad idea. Use one threading library and stay with it.

Comment: I don't understand what threadcount is to you. But the name suggests that it is not the right thing to plug into schedule(dynamic,...).

Comment: You might just want to write a skript calling a serial C++ program (asynchronously) as many times as you have cores and distribute the work across them. Processes are more expensive in terms of memory, but they might not have that problem with the file IO being serialized.